# WebBrowser InvokeScript doesn't work when script CDATA commented?

Tags: javascript, c#, xhtml, invokescript

HTML script tag contains function

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I need execute javascript from C#. My code:

```
var webbrowser = new WebBrowser();
        var uri = new Uri(param.FinalUrl);
        webbrowser.Navigate(uri);
        while (webbrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
var args = new object[] { "ctl00$cphBody$gvTradeList", "Page$3" };
var result = webbrowser.Document.InvokeScript("__doPostBack", args);
```

But InvokeScript always returns null and DocumentText not changes. Does the problem may be caused by the comments in CDATA tag? If this is the reason, how to execute javascript in this case?

Comment: The CDATA start and end delimiters are in JavaScript comments, so it will not make any difference to just remove them altogether. (HTML doesn't support CDATA anyway, so it doesn't matter.) That said, it will probably not be the CDATA block that causes the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the form is named 'aspnetForm'? Looking at the C#, this is classic WebForms, where the system has a tendency to "qualify" identifiers by prefixing them with stuff like "ctl00$cphBody$". So look in the generated HTML (i.e. View Source in your browser) to see what the form is really called now.